# How to keep permissions when :sav file in vim?

Tags: vim

I am looking for a vim option to keep permissions file when using `:sav` command to save current file in another one.

Context: I am editing a temp.sh file and use `:sav savedFile` to continue working in another file. but the permission were reset for savedFile:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 aldo aldo  861 26. Okt 08:11 savedFile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 aldo aldo  861 26. Okt 08:18 temp.sh
```

the vim documentation isn't really explicit about such behaviour.

- I didn't find anything relevant in `:h sav`
- neither in [++opt](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#[++opt]) documentation
- however in this [doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html), it's indicate in `:w[rite]! [++opt]` section

  ```
  Note: This may change the permission and ownership of
      the file and break (symbolic) links.  Add the 'W' flag
      to 'cpoptions' to avoid this.
  ```

  - but I tried using `:set cpoptions+=W` without success

Do you know how to configure vim to have such behaviour ?

Note:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 28 2017 23:18:29)
Included patches: 1-1159
Compiled by Arch Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is the same as the `cp` command will not keep permissions.
But for the `cp` command there is the `p` flag which does not seem to exist in vim. I would actually use `cp` in this scenarios. From within vim it would be something like `:! cp -p % new_file`.

You could also create a custom vim command for that (something like `:Permissionsave` or whatever you like) and store it in vimrc

```
command -nargs=1 PermissionSave :!cp -p %:t "<args>" && vim "<args>"
```